# Efficient OSQL union query from two classes from the same ancestor

Tags: query-optimization, orientdb, orientdb-2.1

I have a complex class hierarchy of this form:

```
- A (common ancestor)
    * B
    - C
        * D
        * E
    * F
    - G
        * H
        * I
```

From my application I need this kind of query:

```
SELECT FROM D
WHERE ...
```

But recently I would like also to do this kind of query:

```
SELECT FROM A
WHERE @class IN ['D', 'I'] AND ...
```

My question is how much is efficient this last query, and which is the best practice to optimize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

trying your query with a sample dataset I've created

```
SELECT FROM A
WHERE @class IN ['D', 'I']
```

and i'm seeing execution time from 40ms (cold cache) to 15ms (hot cache).

Using this one, instead, I see an improvement (3ms with hot cache):

```
select expand($c)

let $a=(SELECT FROM D),
$b=(SELECT FROM I),
$c=unionAll($a,$b)
```

**EDIT**

here is the query using WHERE and LIMIT conditions:

```
select from (
  select expand($c)

  let $a=(SELECT FROM D),
  $b=(SELECT FROM I),
  $c=unionAll($a,$b)
  )
where value = 5 LIMIT 10
```

Hope it helps.
Ivan

Comment: This seems good, but what if my query becomes: `SELECT FROM A WHERE @class IN ['D', 'I'] AND value = 5 LIMIT 10` ?

Answer (score 2):

I state that I don't know if I have understood the meaning of your question.
I understood you want to know if the query is faster with SELECT FROM A WHERE @class IN ['D', 'I'].

I have made a test with 5000 record for class A, 5000 for class B, 5000 for class C etc ...

With the query `SELECT FROM A WHERE @class IN ['D', 'I'] limit -1`

[image]

With the query `SELECT EXPAND( $c ) LET $a = ( SELECT FROM D ), $b = ( SELECT FROM I ), $c = UNIONALL( $a, $b ) limit -1`

[image]

The second query should be faster because it does not select all records of class A (45000) and then evaluates the clause *where*, but only the 5000 record of type D and 5000 of type I